# How to format logs in filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I am very new to filebeat and elasticsearch. I am doing a hobby project and I want to parse my data files. each data files contains the information's as mentioned below format,

```
<name>
<question>
<ans1>
<ans2>
<ans3>
..etc
```

I want to read this data and store in es like

```
{
 id : <separate_id_for_each_file>,
 name: <name>,
 question: <question>,
 ans1: <ans1>, ..etc
}
```

How can I do this with filebeat?

Comment: did you find it?

Comment: @prabello no, I have written a custom application to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, you can't do this with filebeat.
You will need to send your log to [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash), then transform it usign a plugin like [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) and then send it to elastic, if you wish to add a id to the log, you can use something like the [uuid](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-uuid.html) plugin before sending it to grok.
Filebeat aims only to be the harvest witch will read your logs and send then forward

So your flow would be something like: filebeat > LOGSTASH[uuid,grok] > ElasticSearch

If you need examples of grok patterns, these can be usefull:
Collection of grok patterns:
https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns

Grok pattern tester:
http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match